# Can i import single file component using Vue and Vue Router CDN?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm currently using Vue and Vue Router CDN. I want to import a single file component (user.html) to my index.html with Vue router. But when I click on "Go to user" the data didn't display. I read a few guides about Vue router but they used NPM or CIL instead of Vue CDN. 
Index.html

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <!-- `<router-link>` will be rendered as an `<a>` tag by default -->
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
    <router-link to='/User.html'>Go to User</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<script>
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const User = { template: '#test'}
const routes = [
{ path: '/foo', component: Foo },
{ path: '/bar', component: Bar },
{
  path:'/User.html', component: User
}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
routes 
})
const app = new Vue({
router
}).$mount('#app')
</script>
```

User.html

```
<template id = "test">
fsjdfjdfldskjflkd
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's been a misunderstanding. As far as I can tell you're trying to load `User.html` in the way you would load a `.vue` file, but that doesn't work unless you're using Webpack to build your project since the `.vue` filetype is something that the `vue-loader` project is responsible for parsing.

Vue Router CDN means you're not building with Webpack, so loading a component like you're doing is impossible. You can configure Vue Router to serve a User.html file, but that file can't be a template component since in CDN mode Vue Router has no idea what files are on your server, nor can it simply retreive them.

So you need to do one of the following three options:

## Option 1: Start using Webpack for your project

This is what I recommend you doing. You'll find that your project will perform better and will be easier to develop using it.

## Option 2: Use the proper template syntax for CDN

This is for example:

```
var mytemplate = `<div>
<h1>This is my template</h1>
</div>`

Vue.component('mycomp1', {
    template: mytemplate
});

Vue.component('mycomp2', {
    template: `
        <div>
            Hello, {{ name }}!
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['name'],
});
```

You can't load other files as templates when you're not building using Webpack. Webpack puts them into your single page application for you, Vue Router has no idea what's inside `User.html` nor can Vue use it as a template. Vue Router can be told to redirect to a fully functional `User.html` website page, but not to just use it as a template.

## Option 3: Use Ajax requests to fetch the template file

This is something I STRONGLY URGE YOU NOT TO DO, but for the sake of completeness, you can use the CDN version if you fetch the contents of `User.html` file using an Ajax request and create a component from that.

#### I really, really recommend that you stop using the CDN version and instead go for a Webpack based solution, give in to the dark side! Or make it even simpler and use Nuxt.js instead since it's easier for beginners to use.

Comment: Why is Option 3 not recommended? I would think Option 3 combines the advantages of single-file components and easy CDN deployment.

Comment: If it fetches from a CDN during runtime then it's not truly a single page website. Every user would make a network request when loading the site for no reason, and since you then gotta have the runtine version of vue shipped you increase both size and loading time for your website. Plus, CDN isn't easy compared to just having your content directly baked into your site using webpack. CDN is archaic technology, no idea why it's still in use.

Comment: CDN is still very useful for cases where all you can work on is a single HTML file on an external hosting you have very little control over. You don't have to figure out where to host your webpack file or try to make it 100% inline, not to mention worry about where to run your pipelines to deploy the compiled version. It's not archaic at all, it just fits specific needs. Also single page app != single source of assets

Comment: 1. Single html file on external host? With Vue that's basically 99% of the cases, that in no way changes whether or not you can use Webpack since you would still control the source code of the page. 2. Where to host Webpack file? What do you even mean? What host to pick for your website? Do you know what webpack is? 3. Single page app can be single source of assets, depends entirely on how you set it up. At the very least you tend to only fetch multiple assets from your own site rather than cross site assets and relying on other people hosting your content, making you the one in control.