# Pass data from Blade template to Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

This is a new-comer question. I have a Blade template:

```
<div id="app">
    <example-component
    :componentMessage="appMessage"
    ></example-component>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: function() {
            return {
                appMessage: {{$message}}
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

And a Vue component

**resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <p>{{componentMessage}}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['componentMessage'],
    }
</script>
```

So the data flow will look like this: `$message` -> `appMessage` -> `componentMessage`

The `<example-component>` is not working because I haven't imported it properly.

How am I supposed to use `Example` component inside Blade template? Providing that I'm using Vue CDN and I want to keep the `app` declaration right on the Blade template for fancy **data transformation** (with Blade syntaxes) before passing it to component with `appMessage` in the middle?

I have been searching for documents. Some requires `app` declaration in `resources/js/app.js`, but if I follow this way, I can not pass data to `app` with Blade mustache syntax.

Update:

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import ExampleComponent from "./components/ExampleComponent.vue";
```

I have tried adding

```
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

And added **components** declaration in the instance:

```
components: {
    'example-component': ExampleComponent,
}
```

But it is still not working (`Invalid Component definition: ExampleComponent`). Probably I missed some steps.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277538/can-i-import-single-file-component-using-vue-and-vue-router-cdn   I suggest moving over laravel mix and the built process. I can help you set that up if you want to go down that road.

Comment: @Cameron Hi, I do use Laravel Mix in the process, I'm not familiar with it. Also, I updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. I do not need to declare **components** property in the `app` Vue instance. Just specify the component that you are going to use in **resources/js/app.js** and that component will be available globally in Blade template.

Watch for syntax differences between Laravel Mix differences tho. It could be the problem ([Vue template or render function not defined yet I am using neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither))

> ```
> import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
>
> Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
> ```